# AWS Data Localization for application

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-s3

We are planning to use AWS and EKS(Kubernetes) to deploy apps. We have requirement to implement Data Localization. What would be the services, method we should be following in order to implement that. So far we are looking at using IAM to restrict accessing resources and to achieve data localization. Are there any better, other ways to do that. We are using services like EKS, S3, Api gateway. We have application residing in various countries.
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/iam-restrict-access-policy